# Is there a name for creating a malicious subdomain under of legit domains, like XXbadsiteXX.blob.core.windows.net?

Tags: network, phishing

This is similar to domain shadowing, but there is no compromise taking place of a registrar account; these sites let users create subdomains. I was wondering if there is a proper name for this kind of phishing/impersonation attack?

Two examples that come to mind are Azure blob storage and personal sharepoint sites. Both have legitimate primary domains and certs registered to Microsoft, e.g.:

```
XXbadsiteXX.blob.core.windows.net
XXbadsiteXX-my.sharepoint.com
```

We are performing some remediation automation for blacklisting URLs and this would come in handy for whitelisting. I am trying to find a list of websites that let you create your own malicious subdomains under the guise of a legit domain and cert. Knowing what to google would help.

Comment: to make it even more miserable, msft serves legit content of its own on windows.net. Block it at your proxy and watch o365 fall over.

Comment: That is actually part of where this is stemming from, we accidentally blocked windows.net for a little bit.

Comment: This is getting close votes, so I edit it to change the focus from _"Where can I find a list?"_ (which is off-topic) to _"What kind of attack is this?"_